# Deploy/Build Windows Phone 8.1 to device (not emulator) on Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013 Pro on a Windows 7 machine. Obviously, using the emulator is not an option for running it.

Is it possible to deploy/build a Windows Phone 8.1 application to a device (an actual Windows Phone connected via USB) on Windows 7? (I'd find out myself, but I don't have a Windows Phone. My client is willing to purchase one if that will enable us to run it.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Just open your project and see if a debugging option "Device" is available in the top toolbar.

Comment: Need help here. Can you guys take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347714/developing-window-store-apps-in-visual-studio-2013-on-window-7-64-bit-without-em)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, but you should have developer unlocked device to deploy your application. To unlock your device, you can use Windows Phone Developer Registration tool coming with SDK.

Comment: Need help here. Can you guys take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347714/developing-window-store-apps-in-visual-studio-2013-on-window-7-64-bit-without-em)?